# TFS 2015 - Setting permissions per area

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I've recently completed the deployment of TFS 2015 Update 1, we have around 15 development teams in the UK and previously we have always structured our TFS projects as follows:

`Default Collection
            Application 1 (Team Project)
            Application 2 (Team Project)`

This caused issues with sharing work items across teams as it is difficult to move WI's across the project boundary.

Rather than create a new team project for each team, I want to manage things with a single team project and create separate areas\iterations\teams for each one.  So:

`Project Collection > Master Team Project > Area 1
                                            Area 2
                                            Area 3
                                            etc`

in terms of permissions I would like to add in each of the standard TFS permission groups to each area. I would also like to create a root folder for source control for each area.

At the moment I can't work out how to do this? Can anyone help?

Comment: I'd consolidate the projects if I could, there are some annoyances for developers when you split your backlog and code.  If you want to set up permissions so that the various teams can only access Work Items in their own area then you'll need some new TFS groups and then start messing with area permissions https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Work/customize/modify-areas-iterations

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look at the some community suggestion on this topic.

- [One Team Project to rule them all](http://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/)
- [Why You Should use a Single (Giant) TFS Team Project](http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/05/153944.aspx)
- [How to implement a multiple team strategy in Team Foundation Server 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danhellem/archive/2014/06/11/how-to-implement-multiple-team-strategy-in-team-foundation-server-2013.aspx)

In general it is a good practice (I won't say *best practice* as it is not the right thing to do in some cases).

Regarding you question, you should focus on Team to define developers access, and TFS groups for general (e.g. administrative) access.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use the multiple teams feature in TFS2015. It allows you to manage the team members, permissions, work items more easily. And you can track the entire project status from the team project page and track the individual feature team status from their own project page. The work items can be also moved between the teams easily (Just change the area path). Refer to this link for details: [Multiple Teams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/scale/multiple-teams)